# Cannot write Arabic language in MS Word with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, wine, language-support, microsoft-word

I'm new to Ubuntu. I installed Microsoft Word using wine, and I'm having problems writing in Arabic. My attempts look like this:

[image]

The letters are not joining - they are displayed in end-of-word/single letter forms.

How can I get it to work properly?

Comment: Which Microsoft word version were you using?

Comment: Microsoft office 2010 ..

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem. What you need to do is the next :

1- Add "usp10.dll" to make RTL fonts to display properly. This dll can be downloaded via winetricks. If you install office using PlayOnLinux, this dll will be included by default.

```
winetricks usp10
```

2- Set "usp10.dll" to libraries list using winecfg.

```
winecfg
```

3- Run wine with proper LANG environment :

```
env LANG=ar_DZ.utf-8 wine "/path/to/office/executable"
```

The path to office executable for me is : "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE"
Hence:

```
env LANG=ar_DZ.utf-8 wine "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\WINWORD.EXE"
```

You can replace "ar_DZ.utf-8" with your desired language if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu comes with a very old version of Wine by default, installing the latest version should help.

To install, run these commands in the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-staging
```

Comment: so the problem with wine or word ?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but you will be much better off with the latest version of Wine.